# Insufficient memory error in java with junk char size during GetStringUTFChars in JNI method

Tags: java, memory, crash, java-native-interface

During JNI invocation , I am persistently hitting this issue of

> "Detailed error: #,# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime
>   Environment to continue.,# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to
>   allocate **18446744073203188961** bytes for GetStringUTFChars,# ".

I have verified that the variable being read by GetStringUTFChars is only 3 character long, so I am sure this is a garbage value provided in the error thrown by JNI. I have tried increasing Xms and Xmx to 512m to 6g howevver that didn't help.

Stack trace from JVM is:

> Current thread (0x000000004bef4800):  JavaThread "main"
>   [_thread_in_vm, id=638, stack(0x0000000040a9b000,0x0000000040b9c000)]
>
> Stack: [0x0000000040a9b000,0x0000000040b9c000], 
>   sp=0x0000000040b9a840,  free space=1022k Native frames: (J=compiled
>   Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code) V 
>   [libjvm.so+0x861275]  VMError::report_and_die()+0x265 V 
>   [libjvm.so+0x3e5668]  report_vm_out_of_memory(char const*, int,
>   unsigned long, char const*)+0x68 V  [libjvm.so+0x511450] 
>   unsigned+0x210 . .

Any idea, how we could diagnose the prime issue here? 
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post the calling code. The junk value is coming from somewhere.

Comment: That value is just under 2^64 (2^64-506362655) and looks suspiciously like what might happen with stack corruption.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your response, it was occurring due to the mismatch of .jar and .so files.

Answer (score 1):

If your environment supports it, pass `-verbose:jni` to `java`. If your JVM supports it, pass `-Xcheck:jni` to `java`. To see what's supported, go `java -help` and `java -X -help`.

Comment: Thanks for this, these options are quite valuable for debugging intractable JNI calls.